# Trouble understanding how elements of a certain function work

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I am required to fully understand the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double area(double length, double width);
double time(double p_area, double h_area, double mow_rate);

int main() {
    double d_plot_length, d_plot_width, d_home_side, d_mow_rate;
    double plot_area, home_area, time_taken;
    // I've used double for all of these to get the most precise values possible, something I'd only really consider doing on small programmes such as this
    cout << "What is the length of the plot? In meters please." << endl;
    cin >> d_plot_length;
    cout << "What is the width of the plot? In meters please." << endl;
    cin >> d_plot_width;
    cout<< "What is the size of the side of the house? In meters please." << endl;
    cin >> d_home_side;
    cout << "What is the rate at which you are going to be mowing? In meters per minute please" << endl;
    cin >> d_mow_rate;
    // Just getting all the data I need from the user
    plot_area = area(d_plot_length, d_plot_width);
    home_area = area(d_home_side, d_home_side);
    time_taken = time(plot_area, home_area, d_mow_rate);
    cout << "It will take " << time_taken << " minutes to mow this lawn. Better get cracking" << endl;
    return 0;
}

double area(double length, double width) {
    double value;
    value = length * width;
    return value;
}

double time(double p_area, double h_area, double mow_rate) {
    double value;
    value = (p_area - h_area) / mow_rate;
    return value;
}
```

I am struggling to understand how the `time()` function works.

So far I understand that :

`time_taken` , gets its value from the `time()` function: `time(plot_area, home_area, d_mow_rate)`.

The `time()` function gets its values from the function declaration at the bottom.

```
double time(double p_area, double h_area, double mow_rate) {
    double value;
    value = (p_area - h_area) / mow_rate;
    return value;
}
```

However, this is where I'm stuck. The user is asked to enter values for `d_plot_length`, `d_plot_width`, etc. So I cannot understand how the compiler knows what these values `p_area`, and `h_area` actually are.

I realise that somehow the `area()` function is being used to aid the `time()` function, but as far as I'm aware the variables `P_area` etc within the `time()` function do not have values assigned to them.

Please can someone fill in the gaps in my understanding.

To be more precise, I want to know exactly how `time_taken` is displayed on the screen, from the start of the process, to the `cout`.  Like I say I am familiar with most areas but not all.

Comment: Parameters within the function body have values passed as arguments in the function call. So when you call `time(plot_area, home_area, d_mow_rate)`, function `time` is executed with `p_area` having the value of `plot_area`, `h_area` having the value of `home_area` and so on.

Comment: Thank you, this makes much sense !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program, you had computed the following values:

```
plot_area = area(d_plot_length, d_plot_width);
home_area = area(d_home_side, d_home_side);
```

When the method `area(double,double)` is invoked, the resultant `double` value gets stored in these variables.

Then you have the function call:
`time_taken = time(plot_area, home_area, d_mow_rate);`

This is the **call by value**  type of function invocation. A copy of the values in the variables, `plot_area`, `home_area` and `d_mow_rate` are passed to the function. In the `time(double, double, double)` the computing is done upon the basis of the logic you had defined in this method and the resultant value is returned to the function call in the `main()` method.

Please note that the function call is of `call by value` and hence only a copy of the values are passed to the arguments mentioned in the function `time(double, double, double)` even though the variable names are the same in the `main()` and in the function call.

For further reading, I will suggest you to have a look at the following links:

1. [Call By
   Value](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_value.htm)
2. [Call By
   Reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_reference.htm)
3. [Call By
   Pointer](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_pointer.htm)